# Slack Web hook - Attach a git diff

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am looking to add a simple webhook to Slack my team git diffs when certain files on certain branches are updated. The webhook is working, however I am only sending plain text. I'd like to be able to send the payload so it appears the same as if a user were to 'Add Attachment' and set the type to 'Diff'.

All the docs I can find are about sending media or unfurling links like youtube or cnn. Could someone point me in the right direction. I tried creating a bot to read the JSON of a similar message, but it seems much more complex than I expected, with fields like `url_private_download` which I wasn't expecting. All I got, was that it is uploaded as an attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways how you could send information about a git diff to Slack: Attachments and File uploads

[Attachments](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments) can contain text and one image. They are limited in size, but you can add up to 20 (official recommendation) / 100 (hard limit) to one message. They work with all methods for sending messages, including the [incoming webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) you mentioned as requirement.

[File](https://api.slack.com/types/file) uploads mean that you are literally uploading a file to you Slack team. You need to share it in a channel to make it visible as new post. It can not be attached to a normal message, but you can add comments to it. This will not work with incoming webhooks though. You will need need to use the API method [`file.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) to upload and share your file. Slack supports a variety of [file types](https://api.slack.com/types/file#file_types), but for a git diff I would recommend "text".